# can't find picture on storage android

Tags: android, file

I have a code to find pictures on my phone. It works on the samsung galaxy tab but not on the htc wildfire.

```
public class MyStorage extends Activity{

public static boolean mExternalStorageAvailable;
public static boolean mExternalStorageWriteable;

public static void checkAvailability(){
    //Checking media availability
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // We can read and write the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        // We can only read the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
        //  to know is we can neither read nor write
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
}

public static ArrayList<String> getFiles(){
    checkAvailability();
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(mExternalStorageAvailable){
        File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String basePath = folder.toString();
        result = listDirectory(folder, basePath);
    }
    return result;
}

private static ArrayList<String> listDirectory(File folder, String basePath){
    String[] list = folder.list();
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(list != null){
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            File test = new File(basePath+"/"+list[i]);
            if(test.isDirectory()){
                result.addAll(listDirectory(test,basePath+"/"+list[i]));
            }else{
                result.add(basePath+"/"+list[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

The only difference is

in my tablet pictures are in /Pictures and on my phone they are in /Images

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because on the HTC Wildfire

```
"/Images" != Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

usually to get images you better use the ContentProvider:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

Something like that:

```
ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you add the permission for read sd card?

but in your code, check File:

if(Folder.equal("/pictures")){
...
}
else if{Folder.equal("/Images")){
...
}